# Открыть и закрыть окно

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго вечера! Меня интересует, как можно открыть "*окно3*" из "*окна1*"?

Допустим есть "*окно1*", кликая по кнопке, я хочу открыть "*окно3*".

Далее, есть отдельный "*класс1*", т.е. тот, который находится не в "*окне3*", а просто отдельный файл. В нем есть публичный-статический метод. Там я должен закрыть "*окно3*".

Как мне это сделать? Есть варианты? Перепробовал кучу, то "владельцем объекта является другой поток", "то должен быть STA", то еще что-нибудь. Жду конкретных предложений и желательно примеров, ибо на словах вы можете сказать так, как будет понятно только вам.

Жду с нетерпением!

Comment: Видимо окно regWindow не существует, необходимо проверить на null

     
regWindow F1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<regWindow>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (F1 != null)

            F1.RegStatusRing.IsActive = active;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private Window3 _window3;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowWindow3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _window3 = new Window3();
            _window3.Show();
        }

        private void CloseWindow3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewClass.CloseWindow3(_window3);
        }
    }

    public class NewClass
    {
        public static void CloseWindow3(Window3 window3)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (window3 != null)
                window3.Close();
        });
        }
    }
}
```

Либо

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowWindow3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new Window3().Show();
        }

        private void CloseWindow3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewClass.CloseWindow3();
        }
    }

    public class NewClass
    {
        public static void CloseWindow3()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Window3 window3 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window3>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (window3 != null)
                window3.Close();
        });
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stepan  Kurennyh, спасибо большое, за столь важный пример, но ... 2 способ выдает: "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.".
1 способ: при использование метода: "CloseWindow3();" - "Ошибка 2 Элемент "_window3" не существует в текущем контексте."

Или даже: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." (1 способ)

Comment: Мне кажется второй способ должен работать, но все дело в том, что я запускаю метод из стороннего класса, т.е. файла "testname.cs", а не из кода окна. Как быть?

Comment: "CloseWindow3();" - "Ошибка 2 Элемент "_window3" не существует в текущем контексте." - Вы не забыли определить переменную private Window3 _window3; в начале класса главного окна?

Comment: "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток." - Вы вызываете метод закрытия окна из другого потока?

Comment: Я же говорил, что у меня отдельный класс - получается так.

Comment: Отдельный класс не означает отдельный поток. Если нужно обратиться к окну из другого потока необходимо немного изменить метод. Обновил ответ.

Comment: В каком месте?

Comment: В этом же классе, есть:

        public static void SetRegProgressRing(bool active)
        {
            regWindow F1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<regWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
            F1.RegStatusRing.IsActive = active;
        }

Теперь ругается на это. (при вызове этого метода). Без этого все работает прекрасно, спасибо большое. Но нужно как-то сделать, чтобы это заработало. 
Пробовал через "Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>" выдает тоже самое.